# Is there an "in-element line break" in the flex layout?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a simple text reader.

It use `flex-wrap: wrap;` to devide text into pages,

and use `translate: calc((-100% - var(--padding) * 2) * var(--page))` to flip.

But I don't know how to split a single `<p>`, `<ul>/<ol>`, `<table>` or `<img>` into multiple parts using Flexbox.

For example, if the lower part of the`<p>` will exceed the page range, the current implementation will send the entire`<p>`to the next page, but I want to keep the part that does not exceed the page on this page and send the other part to the next page.

Another Problem is, If elements inside is longer or wider then the whole page, there will be some content that will never be able to see or squeeze other content and cause the offset to be in an incorrect position.

But The container's size is dynamic. Only with data from `getBoundingClientRect` is not enough to fix those problem.

So the code also need to know about the width of each "cross axis" of flex box and some other data, and I'm looking for an Javascript API to get inner length data of flex box like `getBoundingClientRect` does to the outer container of flex box. So far, I don't have any leads.

Comment: _"But I don't know how to split a single <p>, <ul>/<ol>, <table> or <img> into multiple parts using Flexbox."_ - flexbox _can't_ do that. You will have to involve JavaScript, "measure" content sizes, and then split content into multiple elements yourself where necessary.

Comment: @CBroe I have made a similar effect by mistake before... But it's also possible that I misread it.

Comment: You might have more success with an actual `columns` layout, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Column_layouts#a_continuous_thread_of_content_%E2%80%94_multi-column_layout

Comment: @CBroe That might be a good approach, Thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

No, a flexbox layout cannot do that. Use a [multi-column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_multicol_layout) instead.